# Swift - prepareForSegue returns nil

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm new to *iOS* and *Swift*, thanks in advance.

I want to pass `tripListData` to a second *ViewController* (`addNewWishViewController`) through `prepareForSegue`:

```
var tripListData: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToAddNewWishVC" {
        var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        var addNewWishViewController: AddNewWishViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AddNewWishViewController

        addNewWishViewController.tripDataFromTripList = tripListData.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row) as? NSDictionary

        println(tripListData.objectAtIndex(selectedIndexPath.row))
        println(addNewWishViewController.tripDataFromTripList)
    }
}
```

There is no error but the second `println` always returns `nil`. Therefore it crashes in the second *ViewController* because `tripDataFRomTripList` is `nil`. Here is the `println` result:

```
<Destination: 0x7f9401cd84f0, objectId: nCK0VvwueZ, localId: (null)> {
dateAdd = "29/01/2015";
dateFly = "28/02/2015";
destinationCity = Frankfurt;
sourceCity = Hong Kong;
user = "<PFUser: 0x7f9401dc6d00, objectId: 71cgaaZcvw>";
}
nil
```

Here is the addNewWishViewController

```
class AddNewWishViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var newWishList: UITextView! = UITextView()
@IBOutlet var tripInfoTextField: UILabel!

var tripDataFromTripList:NSDictionary? = NSDictionary()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if tripDataFromTripList == nil{
        println("nodata")
    }else{
         println(tripDataFromTripList!)   
    }
```

Any reason why this happens?
Thanks again :)

Comment: Could you show the fields of your AddNewWishViewController class. Are you sure you have the field `tripDataFromTripList` declared there?

Comment: Are you sure that your tripListData entries are actually NSDictionary instances? The cast could be returning nil if it isn't a NSDictionary. Your println statements are not completely equivalent due to one being cast and one not being cast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @thatidiotguy and @WayneTanner. I have added the `AddNewWishViewController` class. The `tripDataFromTripList` is indeed declared there. That's why I'm so puzzled.

Comment: Is your segue defined in your storyboard correctly?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Yes, the identifier is set to `goToAddNewWishVC` is there anything else I should look out for?

Comment: Add the log `println(addNewWishViewController)` to check whether the view controller is there.

Comment: thanks @dasdom I've added `println(addNewWishViewController)` and it is indeed there. Here is the `println` return 
`<gr8beta2.AddNewWishViewController: 0x7fb0d06114f0>`

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up fixed the issue. The reason was because after I embedded the tab bar, the relationship between the navigation controller and table views were disconnected. I just drag it again and setup the relationship. It works fine now. Thanks all again! :-)